# jackson rest service returning URI instead of child "objects"

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

I have a rather complex problem that I cannot find a good solution for.
I have a tree like object structure with a:

- `Node` being extended by

  - `ConditionNode`
  - `ResultNode`
  - possible future nodes

`Node` has several methods like:

- `getChildren()` - returning a List of `Node`
- `getTreeName()`
- `getUuid()`

This schema works if I want to get the whole tree as json. However, when I want to get a single `Node` like `ConditionNode`, my goal is to return a list of URIs pointing to the children nodes instead of returning all the children that one node might have:

```
/get/conditionNode/uuid -> {uuid: "...", treeName: "someName", 
    children: [{uri: "/foo/childNode1"}, {uri: "/foo/childNode2"}]
```

So my idea was to have a third class `UrlNode`which also extends `Node`, but that results in having more properties in `UrlNode`than I need (like uuid, treeName, ...).

So I have three goals.

1. I want my children to be composable, so everything can be a child and therefor has to be a Node.
2. I want to have a class that only contains the URI and return that single class as a child representation for single ChildNodes.
3. I want everything to be able to be reverse mapped. So not only have rest services return json, but also being able to map the returned json into the same objects again (mainly for testing).

Is there a common design pattern for this?

Thanks,
Sven